# How to use Effeckt.css?

Tags: html, css

I download the direct zip file from git. I had look into the download file but there is no css for hover animation and i have no idea how to use effeckt.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start Here

> https://github.com/h5bp/Effeckt.css/wiki/Usage

I think proper documentation is not out yes.. you can try the above link.

Comment: Thanks for the link it might be very helpful to me